# Number of Bijective Functions

Tags: combinatorics

I am dealing with the following question: Let $X = Y = \{0, ..., n\}$ be finite subsets of $\mathbb{}$. How many bijective mappings $f: Y \to Y$ exist, so that the following holds for a given $1 \leqslant k \leqslant n.$

- $f(x) \in \{x, ..., x + k - 1\}$, if $ (x + k - 1) \leqslant n$
- $f(x) ∈ \{x, ..., n\} \cup \{0, ..., (n + k - 1) \mod (n + 1) \}$, if $(x + k - 1) > n.$

After some time of think time of thinking, I have not found a solution. I would be thankful for any hint on how to solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your progress

Comment: How do you want the second set in the second bullet to be read? If $n=4$ and $k=2$, then we have either $\{0,\ldots,5\mod 5\}=\{0\}$ or $\{0\mod 5,\ldots,5\mod 5\}=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.